# How to compare one row value with another and extract the complete row into another dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

There is a dataset containing 3000 rows and 5 columns as -

```
Id   Tag_number   Creation_time    Code    Alert_message
 1      GH567       17:19.8       MEI001       0
 2      GH567       58:33.4       MEI001       0
 3      GH567       15:21.6       MEI001       1
 4      GH567       59:33.7       MEI001       1
 5      HR864       16:23.5       XUY056       0
 6      KI964       34:13.6       UYT345       0
 7      KI964       55:24.8       UYT345       1 
                                       .... 3000 rows
```

The dataset contains information on when alerts were created (known as 1) and when not created (as 0). Here the "Creation_time" shows both the date and time when alert was created. The ask is to extract rows based on condition applied to "Alert_message". The condition would be to check whenever there's a "0" occurring is there a "1" occurring consecutive to it in next row. If yes, extract both rows into another dataframe. The end result should look like -

```
Id   Tag_number   Creation_time    Code    Alert_message
 2      GH567       58:33.4       MEI001       0
 3      GH567       15:21.6       MEI001       1
 6      KI964       34:13.6       UYT345       0
 7      KI964       55:24.8       UYT345       1
```

I have used -

```
df1 = df[df.Alert_message.gt(0) | df.Alert_message.shift(-1).gt(0)]
```

The result I got -

```
Id   Tag_number   Creation_time    Code    Alert_message
 2      GH567       58:33.4       MEI001       0
 3      GH567       15:21.6       MEI001       1
 4      GH567       59:33.7       MEI001       1
```

Would need some suggestions on this. Thanks and appreciate your time and effort!!

Answer (score 0):

I would harness `.shift` method for task following way, consider simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'Alert':[0,0,1,1,0,0,1]})
df['PrevAlert'] = df.Alert.shift(1)
df['NextAlert'] = df.Alert.shift(-1)
df2 = df[((df.Alert==0)&(df.NextAlert==1))|((df.Alert==1)&(df.PrevAlert==0))].drop(columns=['PrevAlert','NextAlert'])
print(df2)
```

gives output

```
   Id  Alert
1   2      0
2   3      1
5   6      0
6   7      1
```

Explanation: I create column PrevAlert nad NextAlert columns which are shifted by 1 in regards to Alert, so that is value of alert from previous and next row or `NaN` when there is not previous/next row. I then do select elements where ((Alert equals 0)and(next equals 1))or((Alert equals 1)and(previous equals 0)) then drop columns PrevAlert and NextAlert as these are not longer required.

Comment: Thanks @Daweo !! The shift rows method works fine. With this method can I add column-wise condition like - tag number and code of that row must be same as that of the next row

Answer (score 0):

It works too :)

```
from itertools import chain
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'], "ALERT": [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]})
idx = df[df['ALERT'] - df['ALERT'].shift().fillna(0) == 1].index
print(df.iloc[list(chain(*[(x-1, x) for x in idx])), :])
```

```
  ID  ALERT
1  B      0
2  C      1
4  E      0
5  F      1
7  H      0
8  I      1
```